# tell whether a character is a combining diacritic mark

Tags: python, unicode, diacritics

if you're looping though the chars a unicode string in python (2.x), say:

> ak.sɛp.tɑ̃

How can you tell whether the current char is a combining diacritic mark?

For instance, the last char in the above string is actually a combining mark:

> ak.sɛp.tɑ̃ --> ̃

Comment: Related question: [Algorithm to check for combining characters in Unicode - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051732/algorithm-to-check-for-combining-characters-in-unicode)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the unicodedata module:

```
import unicodedata
if unicodedata.combining(u'a'):
    print "is combining character"
else:
    print "is not combining"
```

these posts are also relevant

[How do I reverse Unicode decomposition using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446222/how-do-i-reverse-unicode-decomposition-using-python)

[What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Comment: This fails for `U+20DD COMBINING ENCLOSING CIRCLE`, or `⃝`.