# Algorithm to check for combining characters in Unicode

Tags: unicode

I intend to normalize to Form C, then divide into "display units", basically a glyph plus all following combining characters. For now, I'm just looking to handle the Latin-based scripts.

To determine if a code point is a combining character, is it enough to check that it is within these ranges?

- Combining Diacritical Marks (0300–036F)
- Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement (1DC0–1DFF)
- Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols (20D0–20FF)
- Combining Half Marks (FE20–FE2F)

Arabic, Hebrew and various Indian scripts pending...

Comment: What has "UTF-8" to do with this? You should factor your problem into comprehensible units: 1) decode UTF-8 into Unicode, 2) normalize.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this manually rather than using ICU or some other library? If I'm npt mistaken, since Java 6 one can perform Unicode normalisation and decomposition even with plain Java libraries (in Java 5 one had to use undocumented classes from sun.* packages).

Comment: If you intend to split characters into base characters and combining characters, why do you use use NFC and not NFD (canonical decomposition)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all the ranges of Unicode points, whose name contains the word 'combining' (e.g. `301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT`):

300-36F
483-489
7EB-7F3
135F-135F
1A7F-1A7F
1B6B-1B73
1DC0-1DE6
1DFD-1DFF
20D0-20F0
2CEF-2CF1
2DE0-2DFF
3099-309A
A66F-A672
A67C-A67D
A6F0-A6F1
A8E0-A8F1
FE20-FE26
101FD-101FD
1D165-1D169
1D16D-1D172
1D17B-1D182
1D185-1D18B
1D1AA-1D1AD
1D242-1D244

I compiled this list with a Python script, making use of the `unicodedata` module.
I don't know what version of Unicode this is exactly, but I think it's reasonably up to date.

However, I don't know if you're done with characters that are 'combining' in the strict sense, as there are also 'modifier letters' and the like in Unicode.

Comment: To determine whether a character is a combining mark, you should test its General Category (gc) property, not its Unicode name, which is just an alphabetic identifier.

Comment: Hell yes, those are many more, especially in the `Mark, nonspacing` category.

Comment: So the answer is basically "No", try to rely on existing libraries.

Comment: Here are some examples of how to test the "gc" property using java: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29111105/32453

Answer (score 2):

OK I did hack up something similar recently.   Enjoy!

```java
  public static List<String> stringToCharacterWithCombiningChars(String fullText) {
    Pattern splitWithCombiningChars = Pattern.compile("(\\p{M}+|\\P{M}\\p{M}*)"); // {M} is any kind of 'mark' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110887/detect-any-combining-character-in-java/29111105
    Matcher matcher = splitWithCombiningChars.matcher(fullText);
    ArrayList<String> outGoing = new ArrayList<>();
    while(matcher.find()) {
      outGoing.add(matcher.group());
    }
    return outGoing;
  }
```

With its accompanying (passing) unit test if it's of worth to followers: https://gist.github.com/rdp/0014de502f37abd64ffd

Answer (score 1):

[@lenz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17052803/67579) covers most of the codepoints, but some were missing. Below a list of ranges found by processing the [*Names List*](https://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt) file. Some codepoints have `COMBINING` in the name, but are no combining characters, like for example the [*Combining Grapheme Joiner (CGJ, 0x34f)* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Grapheme_Joiner). As is quoted in the Wikipedia article:

> Its **name is a misnomer** and does not describe its function; the character does not join graphemes. Its purpose is **to separate characters** that should not be considered digraphs.

When processing the list, the following ranges (and characters) were  found. Note the ones that (slightly differ) from lenz's list are denoted with an exclamation mark (!). Often the range is slightly off, for example because one of the characters is not in the range, and thus the range is "cut in two":

```
  0x300 -   0x34e  !
  0x350 -   0x36f  !
  0x483 -   0x487  !
  0x591 -   0x5bd  !
  0x5bf            !
  0x5c1 -   0x5c2  !
  0x5c4 -   0x5c5  !
  0x5c7            !
  0x610 -   0x61a  !
  0x64b -   0x65f  !
  0x670            !
  0x6d6 -   0x6dc  !
  0x6df -   0x6e4  !
  0x6e7 -   0x6e8  !
  0x6ea -   0x6ed  !
  0x711            !
  0x730 -   0x74a  !
  0x7eb -   0x7f3
  0x816 -   0x819  !
  0x81b -   0x823  !
  0x825 -   0x827  !
  0x829 -   0x82d  !
  0x859 -   0x85b  !
  0x8d4 -   0x8e1  !
  0x8e3 -   0x8ff  !
  0x93c            !
  0x94d            !
  0x951 -   0x954  !
  0x9bc            !
  0x9cd            !
  0xa3c            !
  0xa4d            !
  0xabc            !
  0xacd            !
  0xb3c            !
  0xb4d            !
  0xbcd            !
  0xc4d            !
  0xc55 -   0xc56  !
  0xcbc            !
  0xccd            !
  0xd4d            !
  0xdca            !
  0xe38 -   0xe3a  !
  0xe48 -   0xe4b  !
  0xeb8 -   0xeb9  !
  0xec8 -   0xecb  !
  0xf18 -   0xf19  !
  0xf35            !
  0xf37            !
  0xf39            !
  0xf71 -   0xf72  !
  0xf74            !
  0xf7a -   0xf7d  !
  0xf80            !
  0xf82 -   0xf84  !
  0xf86 -   0xf87  !
  0xfc6            !
 0x1037            !
 0x1039 -  0x103a  !
 0x108d            !
 0x135d -  0x135f  !
 0x1714            !
 0x1734            !
 0x17d2            !
 0x17dd            !
 0x18a9            !
 0x1939 -  0x193b  !
 0x1a17 -  0x1a18  !
 0x1a60            !
 0x1a75 -  0x1a7c  !
 0x1a7f
 0x1ab0 -  0x1abd  !
 0x1b34            !
 0x1b44            !
 0x1b6b -  0x1b73
 0x1baa -  0x1bab  !
 0x1be6            !
 0x1bf2 -  0x1bf3  !
 0x1c37            !
 0x1cd0 -  0x1cd2  !
 0x1cd4 -  0x1ce0  !
 0x1ce2 -  0x1ce8  !
 0x1ced            !
 0x1cf4            !
 0x1cf8 -  0x1cf9  !
 0x1dc0 -  0x1df5  !
 0x1dfb -  0x1dff  !
 0x20d0 -  0x20dc  !
 0x20e1            !
 0x20e5 -  0x20f0  !
 0x2cef -  0x2cf1
 0x2d7f            !
 0x2de0 -  0x2dff
 0x302a -  0x302f  !
 0x3099 -  0x309a
 0xa66f            !
 0xa674 -  0xa67d  !
 0xa69e -  0xa69f  !
 0xa6f0 -  0xa6f1
 0xa806            !
 0xa8c4            !
 0xa8e0 -  0xa8f1
 0xa92b -  0xa92d  !
 0xa953            !
 0xa9b3            !
 0xa9c0            !
 0xaab0            !
 0xaab2 -  0xaab4  !
 0xaab7 -  0xaab8  !
 0xaabe -  0xaabf  !
 0xaac1            !
 0xaaf6            !
 0xabed            !
 0xfb1e            !
 0xfe20 -  0xfe2f  !
0x101fd
0x102e0            !
0x10376 - 0x1037a  !
0x10a0d            !
0x10a0f            !
0x10a38 - 0x10a3a  !
0x10a3f            !
0x10ae5 - 0x10ae6  !
0x11046            !
0x1107f            !
0x110b9 - 0x110ba  !
0x11100 - 0x11102  !
0x11133 - 0x11134  !
0x11173            !
0x111c0            !
0x111ca            !
0x11235 - 0x11236  !
0x112e9 - 0x112ea  !
0x1133c            !
0x1134d            !
0x11366 - 0x1136c  !
0x11370 - 0x11374  !
0x11442            !
0x11446            !
0x114c2 - 0x114c3  !
0x115bf - 0x115c0  !
0x1163f            !
0x116b6 - 0x116b7  !
0x1172b            !
0x11c3f            !
0x16af0 - 0x16af4  !
0x16b30 - 0x16b36  !
0x1bc9e            !
0x1d165 - 0x1d169
0x1d16d - 0x1d172
0x1d17b - 0x1d182
0x1d185 - 0x1d18b
0x1d1aa - 0x1d1ad
0x1d242 - 0x1d244
0x1e000 - 0x1e006  !
0x1e008 - 0x1e018  !
0x1e01b - 0x1e021  !
0x1e023 - 0x1e024  !
0x1e026 - 0x1e02a  !
0x1e8d0 - 0x1e8d6  !
0x1e944 - 0x1e94a  !
```

This results in a total of 814 codepoints.

Comment: Using java's \\p{M} regex against each char in the unicode library, I've gotten 2957 marks. That includes things like devanagari vowel characters, etc.

Comment: @SethWhite: but the definition of combining is not equal to `M` (it is not even equal to `Mn`): https://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/6257 For example `THAANA ABAFILI` has combining class 0.

Comment: Names List has limited information. E.g. 1E944 is `ADLAM ALIF LENGTHENER`, there's no clue whether it is a combining character or not. I think you have referred to the other unicode files?