# Capitalize the first letter of every word in a filename or directory in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to write a shell command where I can specify a directory, and then every file and directory inside will have the first letter of every word capitalized. So

`/doCumenTS/tesT.txt`

should change to

`/DoCumenTS/TesT.txt`

I'm thinking it should start like

```
for i in directory do
tr something_goes_here
done
```

The problem I can't figure out is how to only do the first letter. I've made a script that uppercase the whole file name, but I can't figure out how to only get the first letter of every word.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to restrict the context of `tr`, so it is definitely the wrong command here. It always substitutes all occurrences of the characters you supply as arguments.

Comment: This could help: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/02/capitalize-every-first-letter-of-word.html

Answer (score 7):

#### Using GNU Sed

You can do this quite easily with GNU sed. For example:

```
$ echo '/doCumenTS/tesT.txt' | sed 's!/.!\U&!g'
/DoCumenTS/TesT.txt
```

#### Limitations

Note that the \U escape is a GNU sed extension. The manual says:

> Finally, as a GNU 'sed' extension, you can include a special sequence made of a backslash and one of the letters 'L', 'l', 'U', 'u', or 'E'.

```
`\U'
     Turn the replacement to uppercase until a `\L' or `\E' is found
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 7):

Bash 4.0+ has a parameter substitution 'lowercase to uppercase'. To change only
the first character use it like this:

```
list=( 'aaa/bbb' 'aAAA' 'aaa/bbb/ccc' 'aaa bbb/ccc' )

IFS='/'
for item in "${list[@]}"; do
  split=( $item )
  echo "'${split[*]^}'"
done
```

The result:

```
'Aaa/Bbb'
'AAAA'
'Aaa/Bbb/Ccc'
'Aaa bbb/Ccc'
```

Comment: This doesn't help the OPs use case of capitalizing after each path component. If you can show how to do the uppercase expansion on multiple parts of the pathnames using pure Bash, then it would be a good answer, but I couldn't find a way to make that happen either without multiple passes over the string.

Comment: You can do a second inner loop with `IFS=/` to split the pathname components.

Comment: Changed after tripleee's comment.

Answer (score 7):

```
Source="ONE TWO THREE FOUR"
Target="One Two Three Four"
```

Solution is below:

```
Target=`echo $Source | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | sed -e 's/^./\U&/g; s/ ./\U&/g'`
echo $Target

One Two Three Four
```

Taken from here: http://souravgulati.webs.com/apps/forums/topics/show/8584862-shell-script-capitalize-first-letter-of-every-word-of-a-line-

Comment: Only works for characters A-Z, and not for international characters.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Comment: @svante, look at Unicode character decomposition/normalization, [here](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-18.html#Decomposition) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html). [Decompose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16467479/6505499), check for "bare latin letters", use this code, then [recombine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/446222/6505499). This isn't all `bash`, though one could write a `bash` version.

Comment: Do note that this solution, while it capitalises the first character, forces all other characters to lowercase. Looking at the post, I don't think this is the requested outcome.

Answer (score 3):

Before:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -depth -print
./file1
./bar/file3
./bar
./foo/file2
./foo/baz/file4
./foo/baz
./foo
```

Modification:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -depth -print0 | 
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do 
    b=$(basename "$filename")
    mv "$filename" "$(dirname "$filename")/${b^}"
done
```

After:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -depth -print
./Foo/Baz/File4
./Foo/Baz
./Foo/File2
./Foo
./Bar/File3
./Bar
./File1
```

Comment: The key here is to use the `-depth` find option so that you ensure a directory's files are renamed before the directory itself.

Comment: `find . -mindepth 1 -depth -execdir bash -c 'f=${0#./}; mv -- "$f" "${f^}"' {} \;`

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the loop using features from [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) v4:

```
input='/doCumenTS/tesT.txt'
IFS='/'
dirs=( $input )           # split on '/'
output=( "${dirs[*]^}" )  # capitalize
IFS=$' \t\n'              # reset IFS
```

You can embed it within a shell function:

```
capitalize_subdirs()
{
  local IFS='/'
  dirs=( $1 )
  echo "${dirs[*]^}"
}
```

Usage:

```
output=$( capitalize_subdirs '/doCumenTS/tesT.txt' )
```

This works even on path names containing spaces, tabs and new lines!

```
$ capitalize_subdirs '/doCumenTS/tesT.txt'
/DoCumenTS/TesT.txt

$ capitalize_subdirs $'/d\noCu\tme nTS/tesT.txt'
/D
oCu     me nTS/TesT.txt
```

Comment: unfortunately bash-only, not even in zsh :/

Answer (score 0):

Using rename, you can do this in the current directory with:

```
rename 's/./\U$&/' *; rename 's/ ./\U$&/g' *;
```

Use the `-n` option to first display the changes without executing them.