# Comparing unicode with unicode in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, python-unicode

I am trying to count the number of same words in an Urdu document which is saved in UTF-8.

so for example I have document containing 3 exactly same words separated by space

```
خُداوند خُداوند خُداوند
```

I tried to count the words by reading the file using the following code:

```
        file_obj = codecs.open(path,encoding="utf-8")
        lst = repr(file_obj.readline()).split(" ")
        word = lst[0]
        count =0
        for w in lst:
            if word == w:
                count += 1
        print count
```

but the value of count I am getting is 1 while I should get 3.

How does one compare Unicode strings?

Comment: What does `lst` print as? I have `[u'\u062e\u064f\u062f\u0627\u0648\u0646\u062f', u'\u062e\u064f\u062f\u0627\u0648\u0646\u062f', u'\u062e\u064f\u062f\u0627\u0648\u0646\u062f']` and those are exactly identical (your code works). But if there are any denormalized forms then they won't be identical.

Comment: See [Normalizing Unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16467479) for the proper way to handle Unicode values with denormalized codepoints.

Comment: And remove the `repr()`. You just added `u'` and `'` to the start and end of the string. So `word` is now `"u'\u062e\u064f\u062f\u0627\u0648\u0646\u062f`, `lst[1]` is `'\u062e\u064f\u062f\u0627\u0648\u0646\u062f'` and `list[2]` is `"\u062e\u064f\u062f\u0627\u0648\u0646\u062f'"`. These strings are *obviously* not equal.

Comment: removing repr() gives me an error:
File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map) UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Not on that line it won't. Are you trying to *print* these values somewhere too?

Comment: Your Windows *console* cannot handle these characters when printing. That is a *output* problem, not a problem with the input.

Comment: oh i see, so removing the print statements and repr() I got my code working, but the count remains 1, when printing using repr() I got same output as 3rd comment. I have now removed repr() so without u' and ' this should work fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `repr()` from your code. Use `repr()` only to create debug output; you are turning a unicode value into a string that can be pasted back into the interpreter.

This means your line from the file is now stored as:

```
>>> repr(u'خُداوند خُداوند خُداوند\n').split(" ")
["u'\\u062e\\u064f\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0646\\u062f", '\\u062e\\u064f\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0646\\u062f', "\\u062e\\u064f\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0646\\u062f\\n'"]
```

Note the *double* backslashes (escaped unicode escapes) and the first string starts with `u'` and the last string ends with `\\n'`. These values are obviously never equal.

Remove the `repr()`, and use `.split()` *without arguments* to remove the trailing whitespace too:

```
lst = file_obj.readline().split()
```

and your code will work:

```
>>> res = u'خُداوند خُداوند خُداوند\n'.split()
>>> res[0] == res[1] == res[2]
True
```

You may need to *normalize* the input first; some characters can be expressed either as one unicode codepoint or as two *combining* codepoints. Normalizing moves all such characters to a composed or decomposed state. See [Normalizing Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16467479).

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `repr`?

```
lst = file_obj.readline().split(" ")
```

The point is that you should at least `print` variables like `lst` and `w` to see what they are.

Comment: Even *with* the `repr()` the sample input still works; of course the OP should not be using that, however.

Comment: Ah, no, the first string will have `u'`, the second has no quotes, the third a trailing `'`.

Comment: Your opening sentence *Try removing the `repr`?* suggested otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing unicode strings in Python:

```
a = u'Artur'
print(a)
b = u'\u0041rtur'
print(b)

if a == b:
    print('the same')
```

result:

```
Artur
Artur
the same
```