# Python regex sub function with matching group

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get a python regex sub function to work but I'm having a bit of trouble.  Below is the code that I'm using.

```
 string = 'á:tdfrec'
 newString = re.sub(ur"([aeioäëöáéíóàèìò])([aeioäëöáéíóúàèìò]):", ur"\1:\2", string)
 #newString = re.sub(ur"([a|e|i|o|ä|ë|ö|á|é|í|ó|à|è|ì|ò])([a|e|i|o|ä|ë|ö|á|é|í|ó|ú|à|è|ì|ò]):", ur"\1:\2", string)
 print newString
 # a:́tdfrec is printed
```

So the the above code is not working the way that I intend.  It's not displaying correctly but the string printed has the accute accent over the `:`.  The regex statement is moving the accute accent from over the `a` to over the `:`.  For the string that I'm declaring this regex is not suppose be applied.  My intention for this regex statement is to only be applied for the following examples:

```
 aä:dtcbd becomes a:ädtcbd
 adfseì:gh becomes adfse:ìgh 
 éò:fdbh becomes é:òfdbh
```

but my regex statement is being applied and I don't want it to be.  I think my problem is the second character set followed by the `:` (ie `á:`) is what's causing the regex statement to be applied.  I've been staring at this for a while and tried a few other things and I feel like this should work but I'm missing something.  Any help is appreciated!

The follow code with `re.UNICODE` flag also doesn't achieve the desired output:

```
>>> import re
>>> original = u'á:tdfrec'
>>> pattern = re.compile(ur"([aeioäëöáéíóàèìò])([aeioäëöáéíóúàèìò]):", re.UNICODE)
>>> print pattern.sub(ur'\1:\2', string)
á:tdfrec
```

Is it because of the diacritic and the [tony the pony](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) example for `les misérable`? The diacritic is on the wrong character after reversing it:

```
>>> original = u'les misérable'
>>> print ''.join([i for i in reversed(original)])
elbarésim sel
```

Comment: did you specify the UNICODE flag? it might be required for this to work properly.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Although that isn't a bad idea, it won't actually help here.  See the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit:** Definitely an issue with the combining diacritics, you need to normalize both the regular expression and the strings you are trying to match.  For example:

```
import unicodedata

regex = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', ur'([aeioäëöáéíóàèìò])([aeioäëöáéíóúàèìò]):')
string = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', u'aä:dtcbd')
newString = re.sub(regex, ur'\1:\2', string)
```

Here is an example that shows why you might hit an issue without the normalization.  The string `u'á'` could either be the single code point LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACCUTE (U+00E1) or it could be two code points, LATIN SMALL LETTER A (U+0061) followed by COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301).  These will probably look the same, but they will have very different behaviors in a regex because you can match the combining accent as its own character.  That is what is happening here with the string `'á:tdfrec'`, a regular 'a' is captured in group 1, and the combining diacritic is captured in group 2.

By normalizing both the regex and the string you are matching you ensure this doesn't happen, because the NFC normalization will replace the diacritic and the character before it with a single equivalent character.

Original answer below.

---

I think your issue here is that the string you are attempting to do the replacement on is a byte string, not a Unicode string.

If these are string literals make sure you are using the `u` prefix, e.g. `string = u'aä:dtcbd'`.  If they are not literals you will need to decode them, e.g. `string = string.decode('utf-8')` (although you may need to use a different codec).

You should probably also [normalize your string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode), because part of the issue may have something to do with combining diacritics.

Note that in this case the [`re.UNICODE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag will not make a difference, because that only changes the meaning of character class shorthands like `\w` and `\d`.  The important thing here is that if you are using a Unicode regular expression, it should probably be applied to a Unicode string.

Comment: @alvas That would probably be okay as well.