# Compare ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, iso-8859-1, mojibake

I have a file that contains a unicode string: `u"L'\xe9quipe le quotidien"`

I have another file, exported from Windows and encoded as `iso-8859-1` with the same string: `"L'<E9>quipe le quotidien"` (this is a copy/paste from `less` in my shell).

Converting the content of the Windows file with `decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8')` results in a string that is different from the one in the Windows file: `L'Ã©quipe le quotidien`.

What is the best way to do this comparison? I seem to be unable to convert the latin1 string into utf-8.

Answer (score 5):

Your file is not encoded to Latin-1 (iso-8859-1). You created a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) instead; if interpreted as a Unicode string I had to encode back to Latin-1 then decode as UTF-8 instead:

```
>>> print u"L'Ã©quipe le quotidien.".encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
L'équipe le quotidien.
```

Generally speaking, you'd decode *both* files to `unicode` objects before comparing. Even then, you can still run into issues with [*Combining Diacritical Marks*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks), where the letter `é` is actually represented with two codepoints, [U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E](http://codepoints.net/U+0065) and [U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT](http://codepoints.net/U+0301).

You can work around that up to a point by normalising the text; pick one of decomposed or composed and normalise both strings to the same form; use the [`unicodedata.normalize()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize). See [Normalizing Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode) for more details on that.