# find string containing special characters in mongodb using $regex

Tags: regex, mongodb

using $regex in mongodb, I want to find the name `B&B Hôtel` which contain some special characters like `&` and `ô` by typing  `BB Hotel`.

I tried this code:

```
db.txt.find({ "name": {'$regex': query, $options:'i'}})
```

where `query` can be `BB Hotel`.

Comment: @Veeram any help please

Comment: You can only type `B&B H[ôo]tel`. Else, you'd have to normalize the text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew   would you explain please , i'm a really beginner

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes work whene i search for "B&B H[ôo]tel"  but how a simple user will find it ?

Comment: user can search for "bb hotel" and he expect the result to be "B&B Hôtel"

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew for your answer, but can explain to me what is the basic of normalization of text

Comment: Normalization means converting accented letters to their base representations. However, I see there might be a way to [set collations in MongoDB](https://derickrethans.nl/mongodb-collation-revised.html).

Comment: thanks , i will try that

Answer (score 1):

You don't want regex search, you want [diacritic insensitive text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

```
"name":{
  $text:
    {
      $search: "\"B&B Hotel\""
      $caseSensitive: false,
      $diacriticSensitive: false
    }
}
```

Note that $diacriticSensitive defaults to false, but I never trust the defaults. If you are running with older indexes (version 2 or less text index), you may not be able to use the indexes. The escaped " in the search part is to search for this phrase.

Comment: It is a nice one, I could not find it. Do you know how exactly this works: does it apply the regular Unicode normalization (like with [NFC/NFD forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode)) or does it only deal with combining marks? I could not find these details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-operator-diacritic-sensitivity).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew By definition it works with unicode. The ^ above ô is a diacritic (and any letter not A-z is unicode). A diacritic is any mark on/above/below a character that changes the way it is meant to be pronounced. So your question, as you stated it, is how to do diacritic insensitive text search.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your other option is before plugging in "Hotel", do a "Hotel".replaceAll("[oô]","[oô]")...