# How does the Unicode combining mark \u0300 function?

Tags: regex, unicode

There are several references (and examples) in the Internet on the use of the Unicode combining mark `\u0300` involving the `a grave, à` character that specify the `\u0061` `\u0300` Unicode code-point pair. Why does this not work with me? What am I missing?

```
\u00e0\u00e0(\u0061\u0300)?à
matches ààà

\u00e0\u00e0\u0061\u0300
does not match ààà
```

Comment: Have a look at this link:

https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=6k7IfACN_P8C&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%5Cu0061%5Cu0300&source=bl&ots=CqFhcOvp0K&sig=hKd1O51YH-U-KD9nhF39juQnNGc&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibtNXZ88zZAhWRwYMKHUBdAWgQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=%5Cu0061%5Cu0300&f=false

(book: **Regular Expressions Cookbook** from O'Reilly) and read page 58, 59 for very good explanations about it.

Comment: How do you test the string and regex? Please post the code.

Comment: There are two ways to do this: http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode

Comment: Allan, Hans: I read the Cookbook and, for test purposes, duplicated the code - which, for me, does not function as explained. The metodology is clear.

Comment: Wiktor:
REGEX STORM.NET
Pattern: \u00e0\u00e0(\u0061\u0300)?à
Input: ààà 
(3 matches not 4 as expected!)

Comment: Hans: The problem with normalising Unicode is that I cannot call functions in my "native" regex environment. The two authoritive regex books "Mastering Regular Expressions" and Regular Expression Cookbook" imply that the use of "combining marks" is possible, and even provide code snippets.

Comment: This problem is caused by the character "displayed" as à having three possible codings in a file: ASCII \xe0, \u00e0 and \u0061\u0300.  A regex with \xe0 or (\u00e0) and à matches only the first two codings. A regex to process strings that may contain "combining marks" must match with \u00e0|\u0061\u0300, etc.