# How to compare the same character with multiple code points?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

Some characters look almost the same but have different code points. How do I know which one user has typed? For example, If I want to check whether user has entered `'é'`, should I test it against `c3 a9` or `65 cc 81`? If I check both, how do I know there aren't other possibilities?

What I get in Python:

```
>>> b'\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-8') == b'\x65\xcc\x81'.decode('utf-8')
>>> False
```

I think the same problem appears when you write a regex to match such characters. Normally, you don't see the encoded bytes in your text editor.

Comment: But you're using *the same* encoding against those two characters, not two different encodings.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I might be bad at phrasing. But the same user-perceived character has different code points, and I don't know which one to test for. That's the problem.

Comment: Looks like it's [0xC3 0xA9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm).  Does some `é` exist other than that one?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I just wrote another in the question?

Comment: Decomposition: LATIN SMALL LETTER E (U+0065) COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes but they look the same. In fact if you remove the `==` and print each, then you can't tell their difference.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that you'll ever see anything from the user other than  0xC3 0xA9?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not yet but unless you assure me all of them will be entering `c3 a9` using whatever input method they have this is a potential bug.

Comment: I don't fix "potential bugs," though I have been known to employ defensive coding techniques from time to time.  This one just feels like overthinking; unless you can find a way to test it, I'd go with what the definition says it is until a problem turns up.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Then they come true. In fact I don't see why you decide `c3 a9` is more widely used than the other. Where did you get that statistics?

Comment: That's the UTF definition for `é`.  It's in [the page I linked above](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think that's not a definition for `é` but for `U+00E9`.

Comment: @PaulCrovella That looks like the solution. Do you plan to write a short answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @PaulCrovella Following your keywords I found this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode).