# Strange looking Swedish characters in generated PDF

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I am building backend for a system in Django and I am generating PDF files using ReportLab. Please notice that the dots and circle above some letters are moved to the right for some reason. Why does this occur? Font is Times New Roman.
[image: my issue]

Comment: Are you sure this is the pdf itself, or perhaps the pdf renderer? What if you use different pdf readers? (Evince, ...)?

Comment: I am not sure of what renderer is... i use ReportLab to create Pdf and I am opening it with Preview in mac which usualy works just fine for swedish characters.

Comment: I wonder if it's something to do with [Unicode normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16467479/5987)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this issue is coming from "paste". I had original text in a PDF document, that I copied and pasted to .py file (utf8 formatted). When I wrote same words for myself, problem disappeared.