# Problem in searching a utf-8 string in another

Tags: python, string, text

I'm trying to search for an Arabic word in an Arabic sentence. I know that the word exists but I will not get the proper response.

```
var1 = "Good Case" if "حسن" in  cs_tds[6].text.strip() else "NGC"
```

I know that the word `حسن` is in `cs_tds[6].text.strip()` but the response is NGC.

Comment: can you post the value of `cs_tds[6].text`?

Comment: Does it help if you normalize both strings? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode

Comment: Testing this in my terminal whilst ensuring is in a variable returns "Good Case". Can you provide the value `cs_tds[6].text.strip()`?

Comment: @kederrac Sorry but I cannot paste the value, how to convert cs_tds[6].text.strip()  to something searchable ?

Comment: Provide the `repr` of both strings. Perhaps see also the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info)