# Cannot remove remote branch which name contains diacritics

Tags: git, git-branch, diacritics, git-remote

I made a mistake and named a branch with some diacritics (let's say `temp-à-définir`) and I pushed it to the remote.

Obviously, the next `git fetch` gave me :

```
error: * Ignoring funny ref 'refs/remotes/origin/temp-?-d?finir' locally
```

Then I renamed local branch without diacritic, with no problem. But I cannot remove the remote branch.

```
$ git push origin :temp-?-d?finir
fatal: invalid refspec ':temp-?-d?finir'

$ git push origin :temp-à-définir
error: unable to delete 'temp-à-définir': remote ref does not exist
```

So, I got some questions :

1. Why `git ls-remote --heads` shows my *funny* branch, while `git branch --remote` does not ?
2. How do I remove this remote branch? I tried all commands I saw on the multiple posts I found on SO about remote branches. I guess I have to replace the `à` and `é` by some funky codes, but I cannot figure which ones.

Any idea about how to achieve this ?
Thx in advance.

Comment: `git ls-remote` shows branches in the remote **(distant) repo**. `git branch --remote` shows **remote-tracking** branches in the **local repo**. You simply don't have the branch locally, it only exists in the remote repo.

Comment: Which locale are you operating in? Do you not use UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

You'll probably need to have someone who has direct access to the server figure out what to delete, and delete it.  That's probably a *file* in their `.git/refs/heads/` directory holding their copy of the repository.

## Long(ish)

A remote is another Git repository.  As such, if you can *log in* on the remote, you can run Git commands there.<sup>1</sup>  This will allow you to find out how they have spelled the branch name in *their* repository.

The fundamental issue here is one that is only partially solved by Unicode: characters other than the 7-bit [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) subset (also known as "US-ASCII") have no single standard representation everywhere.  Hence the words "définir", as in your case, or "schön" in German, don't have one single common agreed-upon encoding that *everyone* uses *everywhere*.

Git, internally, tries a little bit to use UTF-8, but it relies on the OS and the native C library to get there, and if the UTF-8 support in the OS and/or the local `libc` is lacking, things may happen.  Moreover, Git stores *branch* names in one or both of two places:

- a "flat file" (i.e., crappy) database consisting of <hash-ID, name> pairs in `.git/packed-refs`; and/or
- tree-structured directory-and-file areas provided by the OS, in `.git/refs`.

If we look at Unicode spellings of "définir", we find that there are two:

```
LATIN SMALL LETTER D (U+0064)
LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE (U+00E9)
LATIN SMALL LETTER F (U+0066)
LATIN SMALL LETTER I (U+0069)
LATIN SMALL LETTER N (U+006E)
LATIN SMALL LETTER I (U+0069)
LATIN SMALL LETTER R (U+0072)
```

and:

```
LATIN SMALL LETTER D (U+0064)
LATIN SMALL LETTER E (U+0065)
COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301)
LATIN SMALL LETTER F (U+0066)
... the rest is the same ...
```

That is, the `é` character can occupy one Unicode point (e-with-acute), or two: e, followed by a combining acute.

Converting these two different representations (one is "NFC" or "composed" and the other is "NFD" or "decomposed") to UTF-8, we get, respectively:

```
64 (`d`), c3 a9 (`é`), 66 (`f`), 69 (`i`), 6e (`n`), 69 (`i`), 72 (`r`)
```

and:

```
64 (`d`), 65 (`e`), cc 81 (combining `´`), 66 (`f`), 69 (`i`), 6e (`n`), 69 (`i`), 72 (`r`)
```

So that gives us two ways the OS and C library *could* store `.git/refs/heads/définir` as a file name in the file system, assuming UTF-8 (if the OS uses some other encoding, as Windows generally does, we have other variables at play).

(Besides NFC and NFD there are also NFKC and NFKD.  See, e.g., [Normalizing Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16467479/1256452).  For Unicode tables, there are many sites; [here's one](https://unicode-table.com/en/).)

When you use `git push` to ask a server to create or delete a reference name, your Git software provides a C-style string holding a ref to the other side (that is, the "wire encoding", as it were, is mostly just a raw C string—the ref and its hash ID are space-separated, so the ref must be a [valid Git ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format) and therefore won't contain a space).  Nothing *really* says whether this is UTF-8, and if so, whether it's NFC or NFD or whatever.

The server then may wind up storing the ref in the file system, which might mangle it a bit.  That probably is the case for your server.

When the server sends this *back* to your Git client, your Git client may re-interpret the possibly-mangled ref as something else.  That seems to be the case here: in particular your server has replaced whatever encoded `à` and `é` with characters that *are not* legal in a refname (a server can do this over the wire without noticing that it has done so; the client will detect it and call it a "funny ref", as yours did).

Normally, you'd expect to be able to delete the "bad" ref with `git push --delete` and the ref as you spelled it on your side—but if the name-mangling happened *after* the server Git put it into the *file system*, the name-mangling occurs too late in the process: the server thinks it's asked to delete an unmangled name, which does not exist.  You'd have to send the mangled name.  However, your *client* Git won't let you request that, because that's an illegal ref name.

(Someone is, right now, working on some of the Unicode issues in Git, in preparation for a future Git release—2.36 or later.  There are a lot of ugly and tricky cases here and I don't expect this to be fixed any time soon, but there may be some progress.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This assumes they're using the command-line Git system.  There are alternative implementations of Git that speak Git protocol, but don't offer the command-line commands, in which case all bets are off.

Comment: Thanks for the long story. Very interesting!
What a pity that we still have encoding problems in 2022. I feel like we are still in the 90's ... :(