# How to compare Bengali homoglyph words or characters in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

```
s1='ফটিকছড়ি' #escape-unicode= %u09AB%u099F%u09BF%u0995%u099B%u09A1%u09BC%u09BF
s2='ফটিকছড়ি' #escape-unicode= %u09AB%u099F%u09BF%u0995%u099B%u09DC%u09BF
```

They are looking the same but are different. How can I consider them as the same string?

Comment: Have you take a look to the [homoglyphs](https://pypi.org/project/homoglyphs/) library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unicode, the character U+09DC is canonically equivalent to the sequence U+09A1 U+09BC. When you compare Unicode strings, you should always use Unicode normalization to fold together canonically equivalent sequences. So, convert both strings to Unicode normalization form C or Unicode normalization form D before comparing.

See [UAX #15 Unicode Normalization Forms](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/) for details on Unicode normalization.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode) for how to normalize Unicode strings in Python.

Comment: FYI, only the normalization to the decomposed form works.  U+09A1 U+09BC does not compose to U+09DC, but U+09DC decomposes to U+09A1 U+09BC.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Ah, yes! In most cases, either NFC or NFD would work but there are a small number of exceptions, and this is one of them.