# Normalize one (umlaut) character results in two

Tags: python, normalize

I assume I didn't fully understand `unicodedata.normalize()` function in Python.

```
from unicodedata import normalize

result = normalize('NFKD', 'Ä')

print(result)  # 'A'

print(len(result))  # 2

print(result == 'A')  # False

print(result[0] == 'A')  # True
```

I'm confused why the `len()` is 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Given other comments (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode) it seems to have been decomposed into the letter A and the umlauts separately, the second character should be the umlaut.

Comment: `print(result)` output `Ä` for me.

Comment: You de-composited the char https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms, you probably want this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633310/10513287

Comment: `result` should consist of U+0041 and U+0308. It's not clear why `print(result)` only displays the first one.

Comment: Check the code page of your terminal. Try `chcp 65001`