# Conversion error in python string with umlauts

Tags: python

Given are two strings, one with a keyword and one with a text. We want to check if the keyword is in the text. With umlauts, in this case the 'ü', I encounter an error. If I translate the string with the `encode()` function of Python into utf-8 I get for the one 'ü' `u\xcc\x88` and for the other `\xc3\xbc`. So it seems that the two are using some other encoding. In the `print()` statements it is not noticeable, here both are output reasonably formatted e.g. `"Münze"` `"Münze"` but in the `count()` function with which I want to find the keyword, it finds no hits due to this error. How can I correct this and format both strings consistent?

Comment: My immediate thought is that you have unicode and some of it isn't normalized. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by normalizing the string. For this you can use the `.normalize` function of the python package unuicodedata.

`string = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', string)`

Credits to Mikael Öhman for the idea.