# Converting Special Characters in UTF-8 file to cp1252 file in Python

Tags: python, utf-8, cp1252

We changed to a hosted web based system which produces UTF-8 encoded files, however we have legacy applications that require ANSI cp1252 encoded files. Converting is not a problem however special french characters in names get munged in the translation into 2 bytes. Not surprising but users are insisting that the french characters be retained.

I wrote a Python program to translate the file as follows:

```
import io

src_path='0189enr.asc'
dst_path='a-new-file2.txt'
outcontent=""
changes=0

with io.open(src_path, mode="r", encoding="utf8") as fd:
    content = fd.read()

for char in content:
    if char == 'è':
        outchar=138
        outcontent=outcontent+chr(outchar)
    if char == 'ô':
        outchar=147
        outcontent=outcontent+chr(outchar)
    if char == 'é':
        outchar=130
        outcontent=outcontent+chr(outchar)
    else:
        outcontent=outcontent+char

with io.open(dst_path, mode="w", encoding="cp1252") as fd:
    fd.write(outcontent)
```

### However the program is failing on the fd.write() with the error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x82' in position 300132: character maps to

I'm stuck - how can I modify these specific characters and produced an cp1252 encoded file? Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.11.5

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use a standard utility lile `iconv`.

Comment: iconv doesn't preserve the special characters it can't map, it replaces them AFAIK

Comment: How do you plan to preserve them? I have a UTF8 file that contains 读写汉字 - 学中文. What should the cp1252 contain?

Comment: Are you sure the characters are coming in as single characters? I suspect they may be combining accents. You say they get munged into two bytes. What are the two bytes for, say, "é"? I tried simply reading and writing a file with "café" using Python 3.9.2 and it worked okay, yielding 63 61 66 e9 hexadecimal as output.

Comment: Perhaps if you [normalize to the combining form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16467505/636009) on the data after you read it, it will fix the issue?

Comment: I'm assuming it's one unicode char where if I do inchar='é'  print( ord(inchar)) the result is 
232

Comment: If the input file says last name is Coté I don't want Cot then two characters, as the file is used in a fixed length import so the import gets messed up

Comment: But what are the "two random characters"? Because, again, if I try it with UTF-8 input "Coté" I get perfectly fine cp1252 output. No random characters.

Comment: "Cotè".encode('cp1252') results in 
b'Cot\xe8'

Comment: `"Cotè".encode('cp1252') results in b'Cot\xe8' which is absolutely correct.

Comment: I just realized, your error message about character '\x82' is very strange. That is invalid in the UTF-8 input but it is the cp1252 representation of U+201A, "SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK", in Unicode. Is it possible that there are already some Windows-1252 characters in your input? If you mapped '\x82' to '\u201a' it should fix it, but more generally, you are going to need to make sure your input is all really UTF-8.

Comment: @DavidConrad OP inserted `\x82` (decimal 130) while trying to map `'é'`.

Comment: Sorry was having trouble getting the characters to work, hopefully this does - the result of using Notepad++ to change from utf-8 to cp1252 is Coté becomes CotÃ¨, this is the same as I'm getting from Notepad, notepad++ and the code in the answer below that just reads the file and writes it as cp1252. Hence the attempt to read each char and write the correct value.

Comment: You are using all the wrong tools. You need to understand what **bytes** your file contains and what each **byte** does in a given encoding. Take the word `Cotè`. What **bytes** does a correct UTF-8 file with this word have? (spoiler, 43 6f 74 c3 a9) What **bytes** does a corresponding CP-1252 file have? (spoiler, 43 6f 74 e9 — count them, they are four.)

Comment: "and the code in the answer below that just reads the file and writes it as cp1252" It does **exactly what you need**. "Hence the attempt to read each char and write the correct value" What do you think the code below does? Exactly that. Your problem is that you are taking characters, recode them, and then send them to Python's file encoding thingy that does the same thing *again*.

Comment: May I interest you in [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) to cover some basics?

Answer (score 3):

A correct utf8-to-cp1252 translator in Python looks like this:

```
with io.open(src_path, mode="r", encoding="utf8") as fd:
    content = fd.read()

with io.open(dst_path, mode="w", encoding="cp1252") as fd:
    fd.write(content)
```

Note how the entire middle section of your code is just gone.

A standard utility like `iconv` will do the same thing better.

Comment: The result from iconv replaces the french character with 2 different characters, as does notepad++ and notepad. This is the issue.

Comment: @user246821 "The result from iconv replaces the french character with 2 different characters" Which character by which two characters? Show *bytes* of the input and corresponding *bytes* from the output. (You are not the first person who needs to translate from UTF-8 to CP12523, trust me on this one).

Comment: Coté becomes CotÃ¨

Comment: @user When you use *what command exactly*?

Comment: `CotÃ¨` is exactly what you will get if you take a UTF-8 file that contains `Cotè`, reinterpret it forcefully as CP-1252 and convert back to UTF-8. That is, do the totally wrong thing, like `echo Cotè | iconv -f cp1252 -t utf8`. You need to convert the other way around: `echo Cotè | iconv -f utf8 -t cp1252`. You will not get legible output on your UTF-8 terminal, but you are not supposed to.

Comment: Notepad++ does no conversion. It simply reinterprets bytes as the encoding selected. That’s why a multibyte-encoded file in UTF8 looks like multiple characters when Windows-1252 is selected.  This answer actually converts the file.

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\iconv" -f utf8 -t cp1252 < 0189enr.asc > test.txt fails with "iconv: conversion from UTF8 unsupported"

Comment: @user246821 No idea why your iconv has this issue, maybe that's because GnuWin32 is unmaintained since 2017?

Comment: The really odd thing is a user in another school Division just opens the files in Notepad and saves in ANSI format and it retains the characters. So there must be some environmental issue that is causing the problem in our configuration. I just wrote some code that converted the special characters to the nearest English equivalents and they'll have to suck it up. Thanks for the assistance all.