# Unable to remove unicode in specific scenario and am completely lost on why this is happening

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

I was running into an issue where given a string, I want to use `unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",raw_data)` in order to remove a particular problem point for my data cleanser. However I have ran into a huge issue that I am completely unable to figure out and it seems paradoxical.

I got the idea to use the `unicodedata.normalize` function from this post: [Normalizing Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode)

I figured this would work:

```
raw_data = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",raw_data)
```

In order to try to solve problem I thought maybe for each line I could apply normalization, thought maybe my string was too big! So I went line by line, discovered it was not about length of string. I thought maybe the command didn't work. I tested this out for myself in a new window and just ran Python.

When I imported `unicodedata`, and entered the following line:

```
unicodedata.normalize("NFKD","Clean the Ice Cream Maker –\xa0Use a damp cloth or sponge to wipe down the outside and inside of the ice cream maker to remove dust or dirt.")
```

The output was: `"Clean the Ice Cream Maker – Use a damp cloth or sponge to wipe down the outside and inside of the ice cream maker to remove dust or dirt."` - EXACTLY what I wanted!

I will break down the issue into a scenario reproducible by any user:

Suppose `raw_data = "\n\n1. Clean the Ice Cream Maker –\xa0Use a damp cloth or sponge to wipe down the outside and inside of the ice cream maker to remove dust or dirt."` (taken from Google Sheets using `pandas` module and `gspread`).

I would then take this `raw_data string` (which would usually contain many many lines with `\n` and listing) and create a list of each line (call this list `input_lines`) which would be defined by splitting the string via `"\\n"`. This was what the code looked like where my problem occurs:

```
for line in input_lines[0]:
    print(line)
    print(unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",line))
    if line != unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",line):
        ...
```

This `input_lines` list contains `"1. Clean the Ice Cream Maker –\xa0Use a damp cloth or sponge to wipe down the outside and inside of the ice cream maker to remove dust or dirt."`.

However when it came time to evaluate when: `line = "1. Clean the Ice Cream Maker –\xa0Use a damp cloth or sponge to wipe down the outside and inside of the ice cream maker to remove dust or dirt."`

`print(line)` = `"1. Clean the Ice Cream Maker –\xa0Use a damp cloth or sponge to wipe down the outside and inside of the ice cream maker to remove dust or dirt."`

`print(unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",line))` = `"1. Clean the Ice Cream Maker –\xa0Use a damp cloth or sponge to wipe down the outside and inside of the ice cream maker to remove dust or dirt."`

Yet if I had simply manually put this string into the function:

`print(unicodedata.normalize("NFKD","1. Clean the Ice Cream Maker –\xa0Use a damp cloth or sponge to wipe down the outside and inside of the ice cream maker to remove dust or dirt."))` = `"1. Clean the Ice Cream Maker – Use a damp cloth or sponge to wipe down the outside and inside of the ice cream maker to remove dust or dirt."`

I have tried anything I could to get around this, I fundamentally do not understand what is happening here and it appears to be consuming my soul so any help would be greatly appreciated.

To answer question in comments, when I do `repr(line)` when `line = "1. Clean the Ice Cream Maker –\xa0Use a damp cloth or sponge to wipe down the outside and inside of the ice cream maker to remove dust or dirt."` in the `for` loop, the result is double \ rather than single.

Comment: What is the output of `print(repr(line))` in each case?

Comment: @MichaelRuth I am seeing there is a change in \xa0 into \\xa0 and when I try this new string in the manual attempt I am actually seeing the issue. So this is a great start.

Comment: Looks like a representation difference between `'\xa0'` and whatever `pandas`/`gspread` is doing. My bet is that they're treating the value as a string rather than bytes and escaping the byte sequence. Also note that byte `a0` is a no-break space in unicode and this is supposed to be used _before_ an endash rather than after. Though, in this case, I'd say a NBSP should both precede and follow the endash.

Comment: Maybe there's an option to have `gspread` or `pandas` treat the values in that column as bytes. If so, you'll probably need to specify encoding.

Comment: For my purposes I actually just ended up constructing a work around where I would find the position of "\\x" and do line = line[:line.find("\\x")]+line[line.find("\\x")+4:] 
Also did this for combinations so I also did: line = line[:line.find("\\u")]+line[line.find("\\u")+6:] to completely remove them.

Comment: But the real issue I seem to be having is whenever I try to remove the unicode escape sequence, in pretty much any way I possibly could in conventional methods of removing unicode, it appears to fail. I figure that this is because in python the string will want to be represented in reality as "\\xa0" rather than "\xa0". So when I input it manually with a single "\" it would work. In the examples where it isn't, repr(line) has \\xa0 which is what I am deducing my issue actually was. I still have no idea how to address this issue directly in python. I would love to know. Hopefully this clarifies

Comment: I believe this is the case because when I would try to manipulate it based on splicing like the solution I ended up doing. I would do something like this: unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", repr(line)[repr(line).find("\\x")]:-1). where repr(line)[repr(line).find("\\x") = \xa0Use.......| where I would take off the 1st \ in \\xa0. However when I would repr( \xa0Use.......) i would get  \\xa0Use....... Seems recursive enough to give up on that front. But curiosity still has me on what the solution to this is using unicodedata module.

Comment: I think this is really an issue of how the data are getting into the spreadsheet rather than how they are being consumed - garbage in = garbage out. Also, the non [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question here is "How do I handle these data?" rather than "How do I use `unicodedata` to handle these data?" I'm glad that you're trying to understand, but asking about an attempted solution rather than the actual problem isn't really the purpose of [so]. This is what documentation is for.

Comment: perhaps this is similar to your suggestion? I even tried doing line = line.encode("unicode-escape") and then line = line.decode("unicode-escape"). (- for google api calls) and also line = line.encoder("unicode_escape") followed by line = line.decode("unicode_escape"). This also failed to work.

Comment: Then I suppose I can close this question, I do not really need another answer. Thank you for your help, your input definitely helped me reach a solution.

Comment: I'd keep it open a little longer. There are some folks here with more unicode experience than I and I bet they'll have more insight. Plus, I bet this isn't an uncommon problem. Maybe rephrase to omit the `unicodedata.normalize()` requirement.

Comment: using `.encode("unicode-escape")` and later `.decode("unicode-escape")` can't change it - because it goes back to original value. You may need to mix `"unicode-escape"` with `"raw-unicode-escape"`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue myself thanks to the help from michael ruth in the comments.

I simply found the position of the unicode escape sequence using .find function and offset by expected values that follow the syntax:

```
line = line[:line.find("\\x")] + line[line.find("\\x")+4:]
```

I also did this for combinations of unicode using the same logic:

```
line = line[:line.find("\\u")] + line[line.find("\\u")+6:]
```

Comment: So you are changing U+00A0 into U+00A0? `\xA0` is Pythons representation of U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE. This is treated identically to the character if types directly. I.e. `print('\xA0' == ' ')`, where the second string is No-BREAK SPACE will return `True`. Your converts escaped NO-BREAK SPACE ot the character NO_BREAK SPACE, but these are identical. Normally I want to clean data and convert \xA0 to a normal space.  Which is what you attempted to do in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.encode("unicode-escape")` and later `.decode("unicode-escape")` can't change it - because it goes back to original value.

You may need to mix `"unicode-escape"` with `"raw-unicode-escape"`

```
text = 'Clean the Ice Cream Maker \\u2013\\xa0Use a damp cloth'

print(text)
```

Gives

```
Clean the Ice Cream Maker \u2013\xa0Use a damp cloth
```

But

```
print(text.encode('raw-unicode-escape').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

Gives

```
Clean the Ice Cream Maker – Use a damp cloth
```

You have to test it on rest of your text.

---

BTW:

Sometimes you can get `\` in text when you get data as `bytes` and you use `str()` to convert it to `string`.  But this should add `b'` at the beginning.

As I remember `Python 2` had problems with conversion because it kept `string` as `bytes` instead of `unicode`

Comment: the OP doesn't have double encoded escapes, rather its a standard Python escape characater

Comment: @Andj if OP sees \ on screen when OP runs `print(line)` then it has double \\ in `line`. Besides solution in other answer uses `find("\\x")` with double \\ - so it also suggests that it has \\ in original text.

Comment: examples in OP show single \ in strings rather than \\, and show no \ in output of print. The OP's supplied answer assumes \ rather than \\.

Comment: @Andj in question I see `print(line) = "1. Clean the Ice Cream Maker –\xa0U ...` and it shows that `print()` displays `\xa0` - so original string should have \\ . And OP wrote own answer which uses `find("\\x")` - and this also suggest that it has strings with \\ . But we can't see original code on OP's computer, and we can't test our code on his computer - so OP should decide which answer resolves his problem.

Comment: The question is rather confusingly worded. In every instance when he gave the contents of line using `\xA0` not `\\xA0`. The output from unicodedata.normalize() was whitespace, the output of repr() was `\\xA0`, the solution the poster gave himself, are all consistent. If the string contained a double escape character, repr() would have double escaped the double escape. everything points to the string containing `\xA0` and centres around understanding of escaping mechanisms in string and its equality with the character. The question also touches on issues around effective data cleaning.

Comment: At least that's my interpretation of the question. Regarding `print(line) = "1. Clean the Ice Cream Maker –\xa0U ...` it is difficult to determine whether the RHS is referring to the contents of the line variable or the output of the print statement. An interpretation of the RHS of statement as contents of line is consistent with rest of question. Interpreting RHS statement as output of command implies major problems in the rest of the question, or that the OP in playing and experimenting somewhere double escaped the string. the equality sign is ambiguous.

Comment: My understanding of the code `line = line[:line.find("\\x")] + line[line.find("\\x")+4:]` is that if the NO-BREAK SPACE is single encoded, the code will do nothing, i.e. you still have NO-BREAK SPACE. If the string is double encoded, the code will remove the NO-BREAK SPACE, so resultant string would be `'1. Clean the Ice Cream Maker –U...'` ie whitespace between `–` and `U` will be removed. Essentially its attempting to delete the double escape character from string. So as to whether the result is double escaped or not, is whitespace deleted (double escaped) or remains (single escaped)

Comment: From my interpretation the presence of `\xA0` in the string is a furphy. But I could be wrong. But its the only way to make sense of the question as a whole, The alternative interpretation is that the OP has two different versions of  `line` that somehow got double encoded during the experiments.

Comment: @Andj as I said we can't see OP computer - so we can't be sure how it really looks like and we can only guess. Frankly, I already forgot this question.

Comment: fair enough. Question was far from ideal.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer:

```py
def codepoint(char:str) -> str:
    return f'U+{ord(char):04x}'
line = "1. Clean the Ice Cream Maker –\xa0Use a damp cloth or sponge to wipe down the outside and inside of the ice cream maker to remove dust or dirt."
i = line.index('\xa0')
print(codepoint(line[i]))
# U+00a0
```

The function `codepoint()` is a convenience function to convert a single character to its codepoint designation using a minimum of four hexadecimal digits.

`\xA0` resolves to U+00A0 (NO-BREAK SPACE). As a UTF-8 byte sequence it would be b'\xc2\xa0'

Python 3 strings consist of the character itself, a hex escape (if the character resolves to two hexadecimal digits `\xA0`. The Unicode escape notation `\u00A0` or `\U000000A0`, or alternatively by the character name: `\N{NO-BREAK SPACE}`

```py
codepoint(' ')
# 'U+00a0'
codepoint('\xA0')
# 'U+00a0'
codepoint('\u00A0')
# 'U+00a0'
codepoint('\U000000A0')
# 'U+00a0'
codepoint('\N{NO-BREAK SPACE}')
# 'U+00a0'
```

Each of these representations are treated equally.

Using the code from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77615976/unable-to-remove-unicode-in-specific-scenario-and-am-completely-lost-on-why-this/77617126#77616910) above:

```py
oline = line[:line.find("\\x")] + line[line.find("\\x")+4:]
codepoint(oline[i])
# 'U+00a0'
```

Essentially, if the string is single escaped (`\xA0`) the code will do nothing, the NON-BREAK SPACE will remain. If it is double-escaped, it will delete the code will remove `\\xA0`.

It's the same character either way:

```py
print('\xA0' == ' ')
# True
```

In the OP, initially `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', line)` was used to normalise or clean the data. This will convert U+00A0 to U+0020:

```py
import unicodedata as ud
o2line = ud.normalize('NFKD', line)
codepoint(o2line[i])
# 'U+0020'
```

At this point NO-BREAK SPACE has been converted to SPACE, which is a common procedure in data cleaning. This is what the OP was attempting to do initially.

NFKD normalisation can change other things in the data, and unless you know exactly what is in your data before processing, unintended changes can occur.

An alternative is to use replacement and directly target the characters you want to change:

```py
o3line = line.replace('\xA0', ' ')
codepoint(o3line[i]) 
# 'U+0020'
```

This will convert all NO-BREAK SPACE characters to a SPACE character.

Alternative, we could use regex:

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\s')
o4line = re.sub(pattern, ' ', line)
codepoint(o4line[i])
# 'U+0020'
```

This will convert each whitespace character to a SPACE character. Although I would use the regex pattern `r'\s+'` so that multiple whitespace characters are collapsed into a single space.

In my projects I tend to use PyICU instead.