Why is this code not extracting Hindi text exactly similar from the given pdf
I am using the following Python code with PyMuPDF to extract Hindi text from a PDF file. My goal is to extract the text exactly as it appears in the PDF, but the output is not the same as the original text.
import pymupdf

def extract_pdf_text_font_adjust(pdf_path):
    doc = pymupdf.open(pdf_path)
    full_text = ""

    for page_num in range(doc.page_count):
        page = doc.load_page(page_num)
        text = page.get_text("text")
        full_text += text + "\n\n"
    
    return full_text

pdf_path = r"Kahai Kabir Diwana (Kabir)-2.pdf"
full_text = extract_pdf_text_font_adjust(pdf_path)
print(full_text)

GENERATED OUTPUT:
;2 
कहै कबीर दीवाना 
पहला प्रवचन 
मैं ही इक बौराना 
 
जब मैं भूला रे भाई, मेरे सि गुरु जुगि लखाई।  
ककररया करम अचार मैं छाड़ा, छाड़ा िीरथ नहाना।  
सगरी दुतनया भई सुनायी, मैं ही इक बौराना।।  
ना मैं जानूं सेवा बंदगी ना मैं घंट बजाई।  
ना मैं मूरि धरर ससंहासन ना मैं पुहुप चढ़ाई।।  
ना हरर रीझै जब िप कीन्हे ना काया के जारे।  
ना हरर रीझै धोति छाड़े ना पांचों के मारे।।  
दाया रतख धरम को पाले जगसूं रहै उदासी।  
अपना सा तजव सबको जाने िातह तमले अतनवासी।।  
सहे कसबद बदा को त्यागे छाड़े गरब गुमाना।  
सत्य नाम िातह को तमतल है कहै कबीर कदवाना।।  

I have highlighted the differences in the output and the original text.

Links to download the file
The PDF was generated from the Microsoft word, Also when I copy the text from pdf, I get the exact same output that the code is generating, which is still not valid.
How to handle the font on this? What is the reason for this? Any alternative of this, other than OCR?

Are the only differences the (lack of) font and other styling in the extracted text?  get_text only extracts the plain text.  If you want to analyse fonts, etcetera, look at this section: https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-text.html#how-to-analyze-font-characteristics

i don't want the other styling as well, i wanted the plain text but with exactly the same characters and words from the pdf.

So please highlight where the differences in the text are.  'Cos I can't see them.

I have uploaded the pdf and the highlighted the output.

OK ... so that looks like Unicode combining characters have been used to join characters together.  You could normalizing the characters into XXX form; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization

For info, when I use cut and paste to copy one of those words from the original document to a Unicode-capable shell, I get a similar effect to what you are seeing.  I suspect that you might just be seeing that your shell's Unicode rendering code (like mine) doesn't know the right way to render that sequence.  I suggest that you modify your python code to step through the Unicode codepoints and compare them against the Unicode standard.

That is usually the way text is written into a PDF, especially languages that are not simplified like Euro-Latin-American sequential text.
You can see MS Word's written sequencing here. Single letters work best, but combined letters like ligatures (fi fl etc.) are usually an en/decoding failure. Also I see the file was "optimised".
ककररया
 
क
र
म


There are many irregularities in the file so let's clip them as encountered many may just be adding to confusion.
/Producer(iLovePDF)
/Lang(ru-RU)
/P <</Lang(en-US)
BT
/F0 12 Tf 1 0 0 1 100.62 676.35 Tm
[<1CF0>7.0000007<0577>-20.000002<1CEF>7.0000007<0592>-13<0591>-24.000002<059E>] TJ
/F1 12 Tf 1 0 0 1 133.68001 676.35 Tm ( ) Tj
/F0 12 Tf 1 0 0 1 136.68001 676.35 Tm <0577> Tj
1 0 0 1 144.72 676.35 Tm <0592> Tj
1 0 0 1 150.6 676.35 Tm <0590> Tj
/F1 12 Tf 1 0 0 1 158.45001 676.35 Tm ( ) Tj
/F0 12 Tf 1 0 0 1 161.45001 676.35 Tm [<0567>6.0000007<057C059E>7.0000007<0592>] TJ

So the contents are either American English or Russian.
And the line of text is 2 mixed fonts of Arial Unicode (/F0) with Arial Spacebars (/F1)
What about the text ? logically it looks good. <0577>=क <0592>=र seem well positioned but are not Armenian and Hebrew!
<1CF0><0577><1CEF><0592><0591><059E> ( ) <0577><0592><0590>
And when we try to see how those numbers are to be reassigned into real world Unicode we find the table is really jumbled like it has been tossed in to a compressed grinder of digits that now have no real human meanings. Perhaps something was used as a PDF compressor? OR they were not compiled correctly in the first place.
One of the frequent PDF oddities in this area is the reversed pairing. So to get the plain text किरिया करम on the left the order in the ink repro would need to be visually reversed by a shift of the 1st and 3rd glyph!

How can such a mix be replaced is to Write the codes in a MS word Processor as
BT
/F1 11 Tf
1 0 0 1 36 789.5 Tm
<059f0577059f05920591059e0003057705920590> Tj
ET

and add a translation table such as
7 beginbfrange
<0003><0003><0020>
<0577><0577><0915>
<0590><0590><092e>
<0591><0591><092f>
<0592><0592><0930>
<059e><059e><093e>
<059f><059f><093f>
endbfrange

so we see 059f= "ि" U+093F Devanagari Vowel Sign I Unicode Character etc.
<059f0577059f05920591059e0003057705920590> = िक िर या करम

The main problem is  PDF as a printout format is not designed to be reversed as an input.


https://drive.google.com/file/d/18FDn7JssyY-glXw-qumTiNm6Oh88TMe_/view?usp=drivesdk this is the original pdf source. The content page starts from second page.

The PDF you think is "optimized", could be reason that it have been split using online tools. I have upload the original PDF instead.

Thank you for your detailed explanation.

I have got the original MS-Word document of the same pdf file. And i save as the file to the pdf normally from the MS-Word. But still I am getting the same kind of issues. I don't know how should i export it to pdf?

I tried with multiple fonts like Arial Unicode MS, and other devnagari fonts. I tried exporting from ms-word and from python library using docx2pdf but still same kind of problem.

I did a very long method, i extracted the each chapter of the word into separate documents. And then i copied it. Long ways but seems it works. I don't have to OCR it.

Firstly The PDF is using a Unicode 2.0/2.1 vintage font, very old, indic rendering has gone through quite a few changes since then. Ideally, the best way to handle Indic scripts is to create tagged PDFs with ActualText attributes for each tag. This is where the real text resides. The PDF format was originally designed as a preprint format based on Postscript. What we refer to as text in a PDF is actually references to glyphs and the ToUnicode table in the PDF resolves the glyphs in the font to Unicode characters, but it can't handle complex opentype features.
